# Emit events halfway execution of a Tauri command

Tags: rust, architecture, vite, tauri

I'm learning Rust and Tauri, I was wonder how to achieve this:

Having any command being called from the fronend, it does some processes and halfway through the event, emit an event to the frontend to show a modal with a message.

The motivation for doing this is to have a file for handling error in each module of the project.

Example:

```rust
//main.rs
#[tauri::command]
fn test () {
match inner_test(file1, file2, equivalences) {
        Ok(_) => println!("Ok"),
        Err(err) => a_module::errors::report_error(err),
    };
}
```

And then, inside the module in a error.rs file:

```rust
//a_module/errors.rs
// the error enums would be defined here too.
pub fn report_error(error: Anything) {
    // This function should know how to properly treat the different errors this module can "throw"
    match error {
        a_module::errors::ModuleError {
            tauri::emit("showModal", "This is a module that can even use a user configuration to show messages in a different language")
        }
    }
}
```

The folder structure look like this:

```
a_module/
├─ errors.rs
├─ main_file.rs
├─ mod.rs
main.rs
```

I would gladly listen to any advice about this code architecture, is this a good practice?

Or at the very least, is something like this even possible?

I want to emit events in the Rust side of the application for executing something in the webview such a showing a toast message, a popup message or stuff like that.

From the [docs](https://tauri.app/v1/guides/features/events/#backend), I saw events can be sent by using the app instance.

```rust
fn main() {
  tauri::Builder::default()
    .setup(|app| {
      // `main` here is the window label; it is defined on the window creation or under `tauri.conf.json`
      // the default value is `main`. note that it must be unique
      let main_window = app.get_window("main").unwrap();

      // listen to the `event-name` (emitted on the `main` window)
      let id = main_window.listen("event-name", |event| {
        println!("got window event-name with payload {:?}", event.payload());
      });
      // unlisten to the event using the `id` returned on the `listen` function
      // an `once` API is also exposed on the `Window` struct
      main_window.unlisten(id);

      // emit the `event-name` event to the `main` window
      main_window.emit("event-name", Payload { message: "Tauri is awesome!".into() }).unwrap();
      Ok(())
    })
    .invoke_handler(tauri::generate_handler![init_process])
    .run(tauri::generate_context!())
    .expect("failed to run app");
}
```

Is there a way to get this instance in another module?
Or having a global reference to it so I could use it in anothe module?

Thank you.

Comment: I think the easiest way would be to just inject an AppHandle into the commands as shown here: https://tauri.app/v1/guides/features/command#accessing-an-apphandle-in-commands. If you must have a global instance you can get an AppHandle in the setup hook via `app.handle()` and then make that globally available via the once_cell crate.